# In VC++ 2013, dialog boxes damage PictureBox contents (drawing)

Tags: c++-cli, picturebox

I cannot find how to protect a drawing in a PictureBox control from being corrupted (wiped out) when I call a dialog to save the form or print it out. The form is saved or printed out OK, but the dialogs wipe out most of the PictureBox drawing after they leave. Yet the buttons and progress bar on the form are restored OK -- so there must be a way to 'protect' the PictureBox drawing as well. How is it done?

Comment: There's no way for anyone to know what the problem is without seeing any code.  Please add an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question.

Comment: My crystal ball says that using CreateGraphics() is a bug.

Comment: Hi Hans, that comment is a bit too cryptic for me. Can you expand, please?  Jim Rowe

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you need to repaint the picture box after the dialog has gone away.

Your picture box will get a Paint event, that will tell you that you need to do some re-drawing.

In there, use the supplied graphics contexts etc to draw on the picture box again.  Probably you will want to write a separate method that does drawing, and call it for an initial view, and also during that paint.  But that's up to you.

Comment: Thanks for that reply, Arunas. I've been trying to redraw the picturebox contents, but only after the printing or file saving. I'll now try to do it in response to the picturebox 'paint' event, as you suggest.  Jim Rowe

Comment: Hi Arunas, I tried doing the 'repainting' in response to the PictureBox Paint event, and that doesn't seem to work either. Any other suggestions?  Jim Rowe

Comment: Jim, as others have mentioned, you should at least provide a bit of code that doesn't work.  We're all working blind here without seeing the patient.

Answer (score 0):

If you will always have olny one picture in your PictureBox, or you will be always using pictures with of same size you can just override `OnEraseBkgnd` function for this control and return `TRUE` on exit of this function.

This way content of your will not be altered by unplanned `OnPaint` or `OnEraseBkgnd` calls.

Comment: Thanks for that comment, Amadeusz, but I don't quite follow your reasoning. I will only have one drawing in the PictureBox at any one time (basically data plotted as a graph), and there shouldn't be any 'unplanned' OnPaint calls. I'll try getting some more information on the OnEraseBkgnd function -- hopefully this might help.  Jim Rowe